# Sequelize where clause with function becomes '1=1'

Tags: sequelize.js

I've written the following snippet of Sequelize:

```
  return context.model.siteStaff.findAll({
    where: Sequelize.where(
      Sequelize.fn('date', Sequelize.col('createdAt')), {
        [Op.eq]: moment(obj.date).toISOString()
      })
  });
```

Sequelize turns this into:

```
SELECT "id",
       "siteId",
       "staffId",
       "timeStamp",
       "createdAt",
       "updatedAt"
FROM "operations"."site_staff" AS "site_staff"
WHERE 1 = 1;
```

It's this 'where 1=1' that's bothering me. How can I get Sequelize to generate something like:

```
SELECT "id",
       "siteId",
       "staffId",
       "timeStamp",
       "createdAt",
       "updatedAt"
FROM "operations"."site_staff" AS "site_staff"
WHERE date(createdAt) = '...';
```

It seems to me that there's something rudimentary I've stuffed up here.

Comment: Facing the same issue here... it seems Sequelize is looking for people to hate it...

Answer (score 0):

You could do small adjustments to your code, as in somewhere you need to establish database connection, you can add the `OP` there like this

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';

const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DATABASE_URL, {
  dialectOptions:   {timeout: 30},
  operatorsAliases: Sequelize.Op  // THE OPERATOR PARTS
});

logger.appLog('Database connection established');
```

With this you could simplify your operators so you don't have to use `[Op.eq]`. Also in your queries you can lose `Sequelize.` so that you can write code that is a bit more like natural language and a bit easier to read / understand.

So you could write something like this

```
context.model.siteStaff.findAll({
  where: {
    createdAt: moment(obj.date).utc()
  }
});
```

This should generate output of

```
SELECT "id", "siteId", "staffId", "timeStamp", "createdAt", "updatedAt" 
FROM "operations"."site_staff" AS "site_staff"
WHERE "site_staff"."createdAt" = '2019-02-05 09:06:43.843 +00:00';
```